# How to "cleanly" query a list of objects based on a value in another class with an associative table?

Tags: c#, linq

I have three classes: `Spaghetti`, `Topping`, and `Tomatoes`.
I'm trying to write a LINQ query that returns all `Spaghetti` dishes that do not contain `Tomatoes` with "blue" in the name.

I have a class `Spaghetti` which contains a list of `Toppings`. 
`Topping` in itself is a class which links the `SpaghettiID` with the `TomatoID`, meaning that a `Spaghetti` can have multiple `Tomato` and a `Tomato` can be used in more than one `Spaghetti`.

I have two global variables, `spaghettis` and `tomatoes` which contain every existing Spaghetti and Tomato.

Here is how it's set up:

- `Spaghetti` has the following attributes:

  - `SpaghettiID`
  - `SpaghettiName`
  - `List<Topping> Toppings`
- `Tomato` has the following attributes:

  - `TomatoID`
  - `TomatoName`
- Finally, the `Topping` object has the following attributes:

  - `TomatoID`
  - `SpaghettiID`

**Note:** for the sake of my exercise, I cannot make changes to this structure.

What I want is to write a query where I only return the `Spaghettis` that do not have associated `Tomatoes` with the word "blue" in them.

What I have currently is this:

```
var spaghettisFiltered4 = spaghettis
    .Where(x => !x.Toppings
        .Any(c => tomatoes
            .Where(tomato => tomato.TomatoDescription.Contains("blue"))
            .Select(s => s.TomatoID)
            .Contains(c.TomatoID)))
    .ToList();
```

This effectively returns every `Spaghetti` where the `Toppings` do not refer to my blue `Tomato` objects. However I feel like it's not the best way to go about it because it seems very ugly and quite complicated, and technically it performs two requests (one for the sausages, one for the Tomato IDs that contain blue.

Any suggestions on how to write this better?

Comment: Please edit your question and add a code example explaining how the actual classes look like. It's not clear where the `Tomato`es are stored.

Comment: What is `TomatoDescription`? Did you mean `TomatoName`?